# Post route not working and returns no errors in laravel

Tags: laravel, post, request

I am working on a multistep form in laravel. When I click next button after filling the first page, the same page is refreshed and it doesn't go to next page. It was working fine properly but suddenly it is working like this (getting refreshed).

My web.php has a route like this:

```php
Route::get('register', 'registercontroller@page1')

Route::post('register', 'registercontroller@postpage1')
```

in register controller, I have defined functions like this

```php
public function page1(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flush();
    $info = $request->session()->get('Register');
    return view('register',compact('Register', $info));
}

public function postpage1(Request $request)
{
    /* business logic here */
}
```

My register.blade.php has form like this:

```php
<form action="register" method="POST">

@csrf
<input type="text" name="name">
...
...
...
</form>
```

However when I tried route in web.php like this:

```php
Route::post('register', 'registercontroller@test')
```

and in registercontroller function as

```php
public function test(){
    echo "test";
}
```

It works fine...
All this I am working on local environment using xampp
Please help someone.. thanks

Comment: are `Route::get('register', 'registercontroller@page1') and Route::post('register', 'registercontroller@postpage1') ` after  `Auth::routes()` in web.php ?

Answer (score 0):

In your register controller you will need to return another view or redirect:

```
public function page1(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->flush();
    $info = $request->session()->get('Register');
    return view('register',compact('Register', $info));
}

public function postpage1(Request $request)
{
    /* business logic here */
    return redirect('register-2');
    // or
    return view('register-2');
}
```